# SQL query to count all the Projects that contain 2 or more specific topics

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if the title clears everything up so I'm gonna try to explain it here. 
So I have a table like this

```
Project ID    Project topic
1              topic1
1              topic2
1              topic3
2              topic1
3              topic2
..              ...
```

What I want to do is: Count the number of projects (Project IDs) which contain both topic1 and topic3 for example.
I hope I made the question clear. The solution might be very obvious but somehow I can't figure it out.
Thank You!

Comment: So given your sample data the result would just be `1`?

Comment: What have you tried so far????  Before asking question, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JNevill yes it should be 1.

Comment: @TomaszGiba I tried this but The project ID should contain BOTH `topic1` and `topic2`

Comment: yeah, I noticed that after posting the comment. Sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.project_id)
  FROM project p1 JOIN
       project p2 ON (p1.project_id = p2.project_id)
 WHERE p1.project_topic = 'topic1'
   AND p2.project_topic = 'topic2';
```

If you wanted topic1 and topic3, then change topic2 to topic3.

Comment: The project ID should contain BOTH `topic1` and `topic2`

Comment: your question says topic1 and topic3? changed to your new requirements

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad I meant `topic3`

Comment: This query will erroneously include project_ids that have only 'topic1' and those that have only 'topic3'.

Comment: @digital.aaron - that was an oversight. thanks. changed the answer accordingly